# Multivariable calculus directional derivative

Tags: calculus

The shape of an ice hill (is given by the function $f(x,y)=x^3-3xy^2$ representing the height of the hill at a point (x,y).

Suppose a person is put still at a point $(-1.6,4.2)$. In which direction (in the $xy$-plane) is the person going to glide when released?

What i tried

Using the formula for the directional derivative, i first find $v$ which

is $$v=\sqrt{1.6^2+4.2^2}$$

hence getting $v= 4.944$

Then i evulate $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$

$f_{x}=3x^2-3y^2$

$f_{y}=-6xy$

Hence ($f_{x}$,$f_{y}$)=($3x^2-3y^2$,$-6xy$)

and i use this and to cross product it with the original function $f(x,y)$ and then dividing it by the magnitude of v. Another hint is that the person is gliding down which means that the direction is negative. Am i correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: I think you can assume it's a vector field and find the geodesics by its gradient, but you might be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively the [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of a multivariate function $f$ is a vector that inducates the direction in which a maximum can be found. It also indicates the direction in which the function is increasing most rapidly, and the size of the gradient is also a measure of this increase. You have calculated $f_x$ and $f_y$ in any point $(x,y)$, to find the gradient you have to substitute the $x$ and $y$ coordinates for the given point. Don't forget to change signs, because you are seeking the direction in which the function decreases maximally.